# Loop for Linked Lists

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I really like this implementation of code but I don't want it to be hardcoded so can someone help me to make a loop for list = new_node(1); and so forth.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
    int number;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *new_node(int number)
{
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        perror("new_node");
        exit(1);
    }
    n->number = number;
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}

int main(void) {
    node *list;

    list = new_node(1);
    list->next = new_node(2);
    list->next->next = new_node(3);
    list->next->next->next = new_node(4);

    for (node *tmp = list; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
    {
        printf("%i\n", tmp->number);
    }

    while (list != NULL) {
        node *tmp = list->next;
        free(list);
        list = tmp;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you keep a separate list *tail* pointer (not only the head) then it becomes trivial. I also suggest you create a new structure for the actual list, and a set of functions to work with the list, like for example `void list_add_tail(struct list *, int value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to add new nodes to the tail of the list then in this case it will be reasonable to define a two-sided singly-linked list.

For example

```
typedef struct node 
{
    int number;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct list
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
} list;
```

In main you can declare a list like

```
list lst = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
```

A function that appends nodes to the tail of the list can look like

```
node * new_node( int number )
{
    node *n = malloc( sizeof( *n ) );

    if ( n != NULL )
    {
        n->number = number;
        n->next = NULL;
    }

    return n;
}

int push_back( list *lst, int number )
{
    node *n = new_node( number );
    int success = n != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        if ( lst->tail == NULL )
        {
            lst->head = n;
        }
        else
        {
            lst->tail->next = n;
        }

        lst->tail = n;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And in main the function is called like

```
push_back( &lst, 1 );
```

or

```
if ( !push_back( &lst, 1 ) )
{
    puts( "Error: there is no enough memory." );
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node 
{
    int number;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct list
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
} list;

node * new_node( int number )
{
    node *n = malloc( sizeof( *n ) );

    if ( n != NULL )
    {
        n->number = number;
        n->next = NULL;
    }

    return n;
}

int push_back( list *lst, int number )
{
    node *n = new_node( number );
    int success = n != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        if ( lst->tail == NULL )
        {
            lst->head = n;
        }
        else
        {
            lst->tail->next = n;
        }

        lst->tail = n;
    }

    return success;
} 

void display( const list *lst )
{
    for ( const node *current = lst->head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->number );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int main( void )
{
    list lst = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
    enum { N = 10 };

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        push_back( &lst, i );
    }

    display( &lst );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
```

You will need to write yourself some other function as for example a function that will free all the memory allocated for the list.

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your question

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
    int number;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *new_node(node **h, int number)
{
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
    
    if (n == NULL)
          return (NULL);

    n->number = number;
    n->next = NULL;
    
    if (*h == NULL)
    {
        *h = n;
        return (*h);
    }
    
    n->next = *h;
    *h = n;
    
    return (*h);
    
}

void print_node(node *h)
{
    printf("Head => ");
    while (h != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d => ", h->number);
       h = h->next;
    }
    
    printf("Tail\n");
}

int main(void) 
{
    node *head = NULL;

    new_node(&head, 8);
    new_node(&head, 9);
    
    print_node(head);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Head => 9 => 8 => Tail
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a sequence of values, then a nice way to get them in a linked list, is to *prepend* nodes while iterating that sequence in reversed order.

So the first part of your main code could become:

```
    node *list = NULL;
    for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
        node *newNode = new_node(i);
        newNode->next = list;
        list = newNode;
    }
```

If the values for your list are not sequential, but come from some array, then it would work like this:

```
    // For demo, we initialise the array here, but it could be initialised differently
    int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    node *list = NULL;
    int size = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int);
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        node *newNode = new_node(numbers[i]);
        newNode->next = list;
        list = newNode;
    }
```

Another example: if the source of the data is user input, then it could be done like this:

```
    node *list = NULL;

    printf("Enter integers for the list, and terminate with -1:\n");
    while (1) {
        int data;
        scanf(" %d", &data);
        if (data == -1) break;
        node *newNode = new_node(data);
        newNode->next = list;
        list = newNode;
    }
```